# adding vlv(virtual list view) extension to openLDAP (LDAP) Server

Tags: laravel, ldap, backend, openldap, ldap-query

Im currently working with LDAPRecord library in a Laravel project. I want to use a pagination function but it's required having virtual list view (vlv) extension  to my ldap server

I dont quite know the steps to add it but from what i found , I created a ldif file in `\etc\ldap\slapd.d\cn=config\cn=module{1}.ldif`

[image]

then I use the ldapmodify command

[image]

but as you can see it shows an error message , can you help ??

Comment: It's called `sssvlv` in my config, and you probalby don't need to load it at all, but you do need to name it as an `olcOverlay: {5}sssvlv` (or whatever the correct sequence number is). But what entry are you trying to modify? There is no `cn=module{1}` at the top level, and that's what the error message is telling you.